# Usar php para definir a largura da coluna dependendo do resultado do while

Tags: php, css, mysqli, while

Tenho o seguinte codigo

```
$result_categorias = "SELECT * FROM categorias ORDER BY ordem ASC";
$resultado_categorias = mysqli_query($conn, $result_categorias);
$total_categorias = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_categorias);
$quantidade_pg = 3;
<div class="row">
   <?php while($row_categorias = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_categorias)){?>
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <article class="mr-categorias-single">
         <div class="mr-categorias-img">
            <img src="imagens/categorias/<?php echo $row_categorias['imagem']; ?>" width="360" alt="">
            <div class="mr-categorias-single-content">
               <a href="produtos.php?&id=<?php echo $row_categorias['id']; ?>">
                  <h3><?php echo $row_categorias["nome"]; ?></h3>
                  <span><?php echo $row_categorias["resumo"];  ?></span>
               </a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </article>
   </div>
   <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Puxa as categorias e exibe através do while, um total de 3 resultados de acordo com a `$quantidade_pg=3;`

O início do while tenho a `<div class="col-md-6">` que está no arquivo css com 33% de largura para dividir o total em 3 colunas.

Mas se de alguma forma somente ter 2 categorias na página, gostaria que a largura muda-se automaticamente para 50% se tiver somente 1 categoria exibida em  100%.

Existe alguma maneira de fazer com que o php ao dar o resultado da largura de acordo com o número de categorias exibidas no resultado do while?

Comment: você quer modificar a classe para os `col-md-*` correspondentes ou você quer setar a `width` da `div`?

Comment: é melhor você fazer seu layout se adaptar ao conteudo de alguma forma do que usar backend para manipular layout. dica de ouro.

Comment: Valeu @Leandro - Dica boa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça pelo php usando uma váriavel de controle, e depois só imprima ela no container:

> Exemplo:

```
<?php
$result_categorias = "SELECT * FROM categorias ORDER BY ordem ASC";
$resultado_categorias = mysqli_query($conn, $result_categorias);
$total_categorias = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_categorias);
$quantidade_pg = 3;

$class="col-md-6";
if($total_categorias == 1) {
     $class="col-md-12";
}
?>
<div class="row">
            <?php while($row_categorias = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_categorias)){?>
            <div class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
              <article class="mr-categorias-single">
                <div class="mr-categorias-img">
                                <img src="imagens/categorias/<?php echo $row_categorias['imagem']; ?>" width="360" alt="">
               <div class="mr-categorias-single-content">                      
                 <a href="produtos.php?&id=<?php echo $row_categorias['id']; ?>"><h3><?php echo $row_categorias["nome"]; ?></h3>
                     <span><?php echo $row_categorias["resumo"];  ?></span></a>
                </div>                    
                </div>         
                  </article>
                </div>  
               <?php } ?>
            </div>
```

Comment: Feito! @Hiago Souza, era o caminho que precisava. Obrigado funcionou.